# how to move SVG icon into div?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to make that white check mark into the green.
I set the check's size into 100px for now.

```
  .approvalContainer {
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: var(--color-background-success-dark);
    vertical-align: flex-end;
  }

  .approvalIcon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

dom structure

```
<div style=approvalContainer>
   <svg style=approvalIcon/>
</div>
```

Comment: You know that there is an emoticon for this? ✅

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of ways to skin a cat here. This could be one, noting that I swapped the svg to another div purely for this example. Also note that the html you provided is not syntactically correct.

```css
.approvalContainer {
  align-self: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: flex-end;
}

.approvalIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="approvalContainer">
  <div class="approvalIcon">√</div>
</div>
```